# IE not connecting to external IE specific CSS file

Tags: html, css

i have this in the head of my page

```
 <!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

inside the css file i have this

```
    <style>
h1 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
color: red;
position: absolute;
top:150px;
left: 400px;
}
h2 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
color: #FC3B3B;
}
h3 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
top:300px;
left: 400px;
}
.image2 {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
}
.box1 {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-color:  #FC3B3B;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
}
p {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: arial;
color: #585858;
}

</style>
```

IE is not picking this up and when i change the numbers to position the things inside the page they dont move. however in a Chrome browser the positioning is exactly where i want it to be

Comment: Link elements are self closing and should not have the closing slash. Not related to the problem.

Comment: @Rob really?  I can't say I have ever written a link tag without a closing slash, it certainly will not break your code.

Comment: @JonTaylor - Really. It is forbidden: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html While browsers now treat it as 'tag soup' (broken html), it's still an error.

Comment: @Rob well you learn something new everyday :).  Thanks.

Comment: @Rob - ive got a problem now where even though its now recognisiing the file it wont change anything beyond h1

Comment: Need a link or jsfiddle. Is it working in a modern browser?

Comment: @Rob i checked in both Chrome and Firefox and they were in a position i was happy with. however IE is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `<style>` tags from the CSS file. Such a file contains only CSS and no HTML at all.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `<style>` tags from inside the css file, this is uncorrect.  `<style>` tags only need to be used within a html document.